# Same functionality as HTTPClient in Codename one

Tags: codenameone

I was wondering how I can achieve something like an HTTPClient.
I tried WebBrowser class but it seems that the execution continues even though the URL specified has not yet loaded.

```
public void testWebBrowser(){
final WebBrowser b = new WebBrowser(){

    @Override
    public void onLoad(String url) {
        BrowserComponent c = (BrowserComponent)this.getInternal();
        JavascriptContext ctx = new JavascriptContext(c);
        // I want this Javascript context here
    }

};
// just a test URL
b.setURL("http://youtube.com");
// Suppose to get the Javascript context here though it executes without waiting for the whole page to load
}
```

How can I get the JS Context from within a WebBrowser context? Like a synchronous execution

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
browser.setURL("someURL");
// wait execution till the whole page in "someURL" loads till it executes the next line
BrowserComponent c = (BrowserComponent)browser.getInternal();
JavascriptContext ctx = new JavascriptContext(c);
```

Comment: Please explain what you need from HTTPClient. I know at least two libs with the name HTTPClient with different programming languages.

Comment: apache commons HTTP Client. Where you need to send request with get and post method and the process the response

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are trying to create a scraping solution?

That's probably not the ideal approach since this will actually create a web browser which you then need to automate with JavaScript. I would suggest you create a webservice that encapsulates the HttpClient functionality and drive it with `ConnectionRequest`. This way when the web site changes you can just fix your server in a way seamless to your installed base.

Comment: Im trying to read a page content. And extract information on it. The website changes are not that of an issue since the website is pretty stable and I have specified paths in a config file. Please let me know if ConnectionRequest is a synchronous execution. Thanks

Comment: Its asynchronous and you should use that coupled with the NetworkManager class see http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---connect-to-a-web-service.html